# Is there a way to download simple data divided by days from Google analytics as csv?

Tags: google-analytics

Familiarizing myself with Google analytics and can't find a way to export data divided by days.
For example, I have this data in Explore
[image]

And when I try to download it as CSV it gives me these values:
[image]

So it doesn't show which value correspond to which day, but even the order is incorrect. I mean I would expect that 0 = 28 may, 1 = 29 may, 2 = 30 may, etc. Or in descending order, but expected at least some order. Instead it shows 28 may as 7, 29 may as 0, 30 may as 1, etc.

And in Reports can't even find a way to export (though in manual it says that the button should be next to the report name, but there are none).
Is there a way to export data in normal order, or even with days values?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this through reports:

> Share report -> download.

I didn't know they would hide the download in share.